# Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured but Umbraco cannot connect to the database

Tags: umbraco

I have deployed an umbraco website. I got error:

Umbraco cannot start. A connection string is configured but Umbraco cannot connect to the database.

I'm surpriced because I do not use a database. It is a simple website. Does umbraco need a database to store some kind of data? Everything is working fine on my local machine.

edit:
Yes there is sdf file and my connection string is:

```
<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Data 
Source=|DataDirectory|\Umbraco.sdf;Flush Interval=1;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

So what now. How can I move data from sdf file to database that I will have to create?

Comment: Most CMS need a database. Afaik umbraco needs MS SQL server (https://github.com/umbraco/UmbracoDocs/blob/master/Getting-Started/Setup/Requirements/index.md). You should have a MS SQL instance on your local machine - it's often auto created when running inside of visual studio.

Comment: Umbraco will by default use SQL Server CE which stores data in a file, so unless you configured SQL Server or MySQL, it's likely that Umbraco uses SQL Server CE. Please show us your connection string from your web.config file, if there's any password, censor that out :)

Comment: @Mikkel thank you, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure the SQL CE file (.sdf) is actually uploaded to the websites FTP.

It is possible to migrate from SQL Server CE to full SQL Server.

According to this guide:
https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-convert-sql-server-compact-edition-sdf-to-full-sql-and-speed-up-umbraco/

You can use a program called "CompactView" to do so.